# User Registration Form resulting in blank page after submit

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to set up user registration and login with PHP and MySQL. I seem to have gotten to the point where it should work, but I am struggling to get anything other than a blank page after actually clicking the Register button. I know that the database is connecting fine, as changing the credentials in my 'db.php' file causes an error. I have tried to make PHP show errors, but to no avail, still a blank page!

Is there anything in the following code that jumps out as something that could cause an issue? There is error handling code which should show a form regardless of the success of the registration, but it only shows blank.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Registration</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>

<body>

    <?php

    require('db.php');

    if (isset($_REQUEST['username'])) // If form submitted, insert values into the database.
    {

        $username = stripslashes($_REQUEST['username']); // removes backslashes
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$username); //escapes special characters in a string

        $email = stripslashes($_REQUEST['email']);
        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$email);

        $password = stripslashes($_REQUEST['password']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$password);

        $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, email) VALUES ('$username', '".md5($password)."', '$email')";

        $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

        echo $result;

        if($result) {
            echo "<div class='form'><h3>You are registered successfully.</h3><br>Click here to <a href='login.php'>Login</a></div>";
        }
    } else {

    ?>
        <div class="form">
            <h1>Registration</h1>
            <form name="registration" action="" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required />
                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required />
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required />
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" />
            </form>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>

</body>
```

Comment: a) string-escaping doesn't completely protect you from SQL Injection - use **parameterized statements** b) using unsalted `md5` for password hashing is as bad as storing plain text passwords - use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` c) try a `var_dump($result)` - `echo` won't print anything when it's false

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you cannot miss or ignore.

Comment: This is literally my first look into doing something like this. Was hoping to get an unsecured version working before applying best practices. However, I am struggling to get even that.

Comment: @LegendEater it's never too early to learn how to do things the right way ;)

Comment: You also should have a `<DOCTYPE [one of the options]>` before your `<html>` [see why here](https://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/Doctype)

Comment: @LegendEater Things left till tommorrow ......... _Tomorrow never comes_

Comment: @LegendEater  I wore those same "I can roll my own anything" shoes not long ago.  Then I read and researched enough about security to discover, somethings are simply best left to dedicated professionals who have gone to great lengths to ensure the best possible security that current technology can provide us.  I don't mean to be condescending, I'm not trying to say I am more advanced than anyone.  Please consider acquiring a php Login/Registration system that will keep your future users secure.

Comment: Managed to sort that. Okay now I can look at storing passwords properly. Thanks for pointing me to the next step.

Comment: @mickmackusa, this is more of a learning exercise than anything. I'm creating a personal project for my portfolio, not a production website.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to some error reporting given to me by RiggsFolly, I managed to see that the column name for email address was incorrect. Fixing this fixed my issue.

Handy tip. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong.

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['username']))
```

You are submitting form and there should be the name of the form in `REQUEST` variable. Do this instead

whilst it should be

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['registration']))
```

Or

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
    $username = stripslashes($_POST['username']); 

    $email = stripslashes($_POST['email']);

    $password = stripslashes($_POST['password']);
```

Comment: It works my way too. Is there a benefit to your way?

Comment: Yes actually you can tell `isset($_POST['submit'])` by this that which form has submitted! And it ensures you that form is properly submitted.